# Stream knitr progress to function for processing

Tags: r, knitr

I would like to convert the knitr progress messages into a progress bar, which I think that means that I need to parse the output and extract just the percentages.

Is there a way to capture the progress of knitr and process it in a function in realtime? The function would then parse each segment of text and extract the percentage.

AFAIK the output is being sent to stdout, so there is a way that the output can be capture, either using sink() or captureOutput() to a connection. Can that connection then be sent to a function to be processed in realtime?

Comment: Not possible for now, but you can file a feature request: https://github.com/yihui/knitr

Comment: Thanks @Yihui - a new issue has been raised for this.

Comment: Any progress here? @NathanWebb is it possible to include a link to the issue?

Comment: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1321